# Segmentation error and free memory though no pointer used

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I was trying a question to print nearest prime ASCII but no output is coming. What is the problem and how to solve it?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int p) {
    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 2; i <= p / 2; i++) {
        if (p%i == 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int goLeft(int l) {
    if (l != 65) {
        for (int i = l; i>65; i--) {
            if (isPrime(i))
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int goRight(int r) {
    if (r != 122) {
        for (int i = r; i<122; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i))
                return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int performAll(int l, int r, int p) {
    int diffLeft = 0, diffRight = 0;

    if (l == 0 && r != 0) {
        diffLeft = diffRight = r;
    }
    else if (l != 0 && r == 0) {
        diffRight = diffLeft = l;
    }
    else if (l == 0 && r == 0) {
        diffRight = diffLeft = 0;
    }
    else {
        diffLeft = p - l;
        diffRight = r - p;
    }

    if (diffLeft > diffRight) {
        return r;
    }
    else if (diffLeft < diffRight) {
        return l;
    }
    else {
        if (l<r) {
            if (l != 0) {
                return l;
            }
            else {
                return r;
            }
        }
        else if (l>r) {
            if (r != 0) {
                return r;
            }
            else {
                return l;
            }
        }
    }
return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int T, N;
    int left = 0, right = 0, ss = 0;
    cin >> T;
    string S, R;
    while (T>0) {
        cin >> N;
        cin >> S[j];

        for (int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
            cout << "i-" << i << endl;
            ss = S[i];
            if ((ss >= 65 && ss <= 90) || (ss >= 97 && ss <= 122)) {
                if (isPrime(ss)) {
                    R[i] = S[i];
                }
                else {
                    left = goLeft(ss);
                    right = goRight(ss);
                    R[i] = performAll(left, right, ss);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (ss<65) {
                    left = 0;
                    right = 67;
                }
                else if (ss>122) {
                    left = 113;
                    right = 0;
                }
                else {
                    left = goLeft(ss);
                    right = goRight(ss);
                }
                R[i] = performAll(left, right, ss);
            }
            cout << R[i];
        }
        T--;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1
```

375
AvfmaLgLRpQadLyThsxVzkUqbFOdxfbLGdpBWOwmAnflENlYFbdhNHerHVtZkaPLgMtNQovVHpwGfHJdXXWAhYrhwXKPxtnpxCIsaXVAkcxTpVprFNeOVcnSEsgIvfqXPRSUASSDCvAGrFJCDbzGLFhrMYWALElChmurLrEeQttIWctyhQXzZUVAYuCIZecBJbXMxlMHFbZxJRTSZJmZAwCggGabVsovqBrdmmbCTaIHDfUunLFntfGzodKqoAKwCassKMDybethRaQgegsOawfNCNrIAkECEKpbwElhvWtlZBEZqJQpEkzpiSjrqZZIHbszUxwuWreXkxFKxSAiKoemIqETGVxcCjweKhbyXxhVKCbNTQBKgHD

```
Your Code's Output
```

> "Your code didn't print anything."

Comment: Please clear up your indentation. I don't see any calls to free (or delete) in your code, so it's hard to see where the error is. Can you use a debugger to   find the issue?

Answer (score 4):

`cin>>S[j];` is accessing `S` out-of-bounds, because `S` is empty. You may want to replace it with e.g.:

```
char ch;
cin >> ch;
S += ch;
```

or just read the whole string at once without entering the length first:

```
cin >> S;
```

Also I get a compiler error "Control may reach end of non-void function" for `performAll`. I.e. it's missing a return statement.

Answer (score 3):

You are trampling over the memory `std::string` allocates.  When you get to

```
cin>>S[j];
```

`S` is empty as it was default constructed.  Trying to add data to it with `operator[]` is undefined behavior if the index is not valid for writing and with an empty string there is no valid writable index.